# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. silex error

Tags: php, .htaccess, silex

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /silex/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once __DIR__.'../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name);
});

$app->run();
```

I got this error when accessing localhost/silex/hello/world:

"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /silex/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Location of files should be:

```
/silex/.htaccess
/silex/web/index.php
```

Comment: what is location of your `index.php` ? and also, `.htaccess` should be placed at the `/` root

Comment: index.php web/index.php. .htaccess in / root

Comment: your index.php should be at `/silex/web/index.php` **as you have set base in .htaccess**   */silex/web*   
Please change base or the location of `index.php`

Comment: I do not understand. My index.php in /silex/web/index.php. .htaccess in /silex/.htaccess. Base in .htaccess /silex/web. What's wrong?

Comment: move your `.htaccess` to root directory (from `/silex/.htaccess` to `/.htaccess`)

Comment: ???? why? my catalog structure: `/var/www/silex/.htaccess`. `/var/www/silex/web/index.php` . Move .htaccess to /var/www??

Comment: Actually it should work at `/var/www/silex/.htaccess`
What is exact error you are getting? did u checked error_log of apache?

Comment: i make request to the `localhost/silex/hello/world` I receive an error silex: 
`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Answer (score 1):

here is the silex complete path

```
/var/www/html/silex
```

".htaccess" file

```
/var/www/html/silex/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /silex/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

"index.php" file

```
/var/www/html/silex/web/index.php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;
$app->get('/', function () {
    return 'Index Page';
});
$app->get('/hello', function () {
    return 'Hello Page';
});
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess should be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

VirtualHost file must looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site.com
ServerAlias www.site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/silex/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And everithing works like a charm! ;-)

".htaccess" located at */var/www/html/silex/*

and Silex application bundle

placed at */var/www/html/silex/web/*

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d.
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
      Options -MultiViews 
      RewriteEngine On 
      RewriteBase /silex/web 
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a good idea to include an explanation of how your code answers the question. It makes your answer more readily useful to users.